# After submitting a form, the value disappered

Tags: c#

[image: Before submits a form]

After I submitted a form, the "only display" values disappeared, 
could any knows what is the error?

[image: After submits a form with error, this staff information disappears]

In the View, I use @Html.textboxfor and use a ViewBag.StaffId value as a "readonly" variable, if i submit the form with something error, the ViewBag.StaffId value disappears

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StaffId, "StaffId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
               @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StaffId, new { @Value = ViewBag.StaffId, @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control" })
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StaffId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StaffInfo.Cname, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StaffInfo.Cname, new { @Value = ViewBag.CName, @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StaffInfo.Cname, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Tdate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Tdate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Tdate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Edate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Edate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Edate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StaffId, "StaffId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
               @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.StaffId, new { @Value = ViewBag.StaffId, @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control" })
               @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StaffId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Controller Code :

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "StaffId, Tdate, Edate")] TrainingRecord trainingRecord)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.TrainingRecordDBSet.Add(trainingRecord);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Search", "TrainingRecords", new { id = trainingRecord.StaffId });
    } 
    return View(trainingRecord);
}
```

Comment: For better results, add a tag of your programming language

Comment: It would be good to have the part before your return View() in the post method of the controller, but from what I see it may be because in the post method, the ViewBag variables are not repopulated. You need to set them before each return View.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You most bind model after the post
for example

```
public ActionResult myController(){
  var model= new myModel();
  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult myController(myModel model){
  model.StaffId = 1;
  return View(model);
}
```

Comment: my controller code:[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "StaffId, Tdate, Edate")] TrainingRecord trainingRecord)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.TrainingRecordDBSet.Add(trainingRecord);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Search", "TrainingRecords", new { id = trainingRecord.StaffId });
    } 
    return View(trainingRecord);
}

Answer (score 1):

You didn't post your controller code. Anyway try this example

```
[HttpPost]         
public ActionResult <Resultnamehere>(<YOUR MODEL CLASS HERE> model)
{

  return View(Model);
}
```

Comment: my controller code : [HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "StaffId, Tdate, Edate")] TrainingRecord trainingRecord)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.TrainingRecordDBSet.Add(trainingRecord);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Search", "TrainingRecords", new { id = trainingRecord.StaffId });
    } 
    return View(trainingRecord);
}